# Horizontal grouping listview in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget-package, visual-studio-2019

We are developing a small cart application using xamarin forms in visual studio 2019. We like to implement horizontal grouping listview in Xamarin forms. I tried flowlistview group but it is not able to bind the header template. is there any custom render available for horizontal grouping listview or give me a solution to resolve this issue

```
My code: Homepage.xaml

  <flv:FlowListView SeparatorVisibility="None"
                          HasUnevenRows="false" GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Heading}"
                          IsGroupingEnabled="True" 
                          FlowItemsSource="{Binding ListOfPeople}">
            <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
        </flv:FlowListView>

HomepageViewModel:

private List<PersonList> _listOfPeople;
        public List<PersonList> ListOfPeople { get { return _listOfPeople; } set { _listOfPeople = value    
public HomePageViewModel()
        {

            var sList = new PersonList()
    {
        new Person() { FirstName = "Sally", LastName = "Sampson" },
        new Person() { FirstName = "Taylor", LastName = "Swift" },
        new Person() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" }
    };
            sList.Heading = "S";

            var dList = new PersonList()
    {
        new Person() { FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Doe" }
    };
            dList.Heading = "D";

            var jList = new PersonList()
    {
        new Person() { FirstName = "Billy", LastName = "Joel" }
    };
            jList.Heading = "J";

            var list = new List<PersonList>()
    {
        sList,
        dList,
        jList
    };   
            ListOfPeople = list;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have used flowlistview  in one of my application. Can you provide sample code in your implementation

Comment: What version of Xamarin forms are you using, as I've had problems with CollectionView headers not binding on iOS.

Comment: You are binding "DisplayName" property, While in your view model I am not able to see that. Please change int to "FirstName". And try with updating from HasUnevenRows="false" to HasUnevenRows="true".

Comment: display name nothing but combine fo first name and Lastname.                                   public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName
        {
            get
            {
                return $"{LastName}, {FirstName}";
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Hi uprightbassfan78, We are using Xamarin.Forms Version 3.3.0.912540 and one more thing I tried latest version also(flow listview and xamarin forms) but no use

Comment: First of all, I test it in my project, it cannot work for Grouping with `FlowListView`,but I change `Listview` in xamarin forms. It could show grouping normally.Here is link about listview grouping. https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-listview-grouping/

Comment: my requirements is FlowListView grouping only

Comment: @P.Thiyagu Can you please tel me how you you achieved  it ? i'm really need of it...grouped collection view with  horizontal orientation for group items